# Show Webbrowser Control Upload Percentage c#

Tags: c#, upload

I have a Windows Form application in c#.
in my application i have a WebBrowser Control. in my program web browser will upload a file i want to show in my program what percentage of file is uploaded. how can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at web browser [ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.progresschanged). This event has an argument as `WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs` which holds `CurrentProgress`  property which you can use to show with the progress bar.

```
WebBrowser1.ProgressChanged += WebBrowser1_ProgressChanged;


private void WebBrowser1_ProgressChanged(object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
    ProgressBar1.Value = e.CurrentProgress;
}
```

Comment: Glad to see it helps you! you can mark this as answer if it resolved your problem.